# Software to Communicate Between 2 Linux Machines Directly

Tags: linux

I am searching for software to get 2 Linux machines(Jetson Nanos) with WiFi/Bluetooth cards to communicate directly. They will be transmitting lots of data from image and video analytics.

What would be an approach to this? Bash commands?(netcat), Scripts?, Software?

Thanks for any suggestions or links!

Comment: Connect both machines to the same wifi network, then find the local ip of each one using `ip addr show`. Then, you can set up an `sshd` service and transfer files between them using `scp` or `rsync`.

Comment: You are at the correct site to ask for an additional software to do this. If you just want to use what the operating system provides, ask at https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You might consider some backup, or directory synch software. If you need something different, please update your question.

Comment: Would you be able to use @markasoftware approach directly between the two machines without a wifi router or hotspot?